# Replication of CouchDB like at mongoDB

Tags: nosql, couchdb, replication

Is there a way of configuring couchDB with automatic replication like it is done with mongodbs replica sets? -> without any additional frameworks?

Comment: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/replication.html

Answer (score 0):

You can replicate a database in CouchDB  by sending a POST request to the _replicate URL.

http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication

If you want to continuously update the future data in the replicated version, you can use continuous replication

http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication#Continuous_replication